# Joining three queries, passing results from one to next

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I've looked at other questions, and I am not certain this is the same as previously asked questions.

Basically, I have three queries in succession. Query 1 results are passed to Query 2, and Query 2 results are passed to query 3, and write query 3 results to a file.

```
'select convert(char(10),max(paydate),101) from DATA.dbo.payment where status like 'PAID%'
'select distinct groupkey from  custom.dbo.ediX091Header_abc where CheckIssue  = '<results from query 1>' and status = 'Go'
'select max(GroupKey) from dbo.ediFuncGroup_abc' where GroupKey = '<results from query 2>'
```

Write any results from query 3 to an output file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Pick one RDBMS system to tag 2) put your results from each query into a table (user defined, variable, or temp) and use that table in the subsequent queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run all three queries one after the other. You can pretty easily join the tables from the second and third queries. Then use the first query as a subquery to filter the results. Something like this.

```
select MAX(GroupKey)
from dbo.ediFunctionGroup_abc fc
join custom.dbo.ediX091Header_abc h on h.GroupKey = fc.GroupKey 
where h.status = 'Go'
    and h.CheckIssue = (select CONVERT(char(10), max(paydate)) from DATA.dbo.payment where status like 'PAID%')
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. Appreciate it!

Comment: If that works for you then you should consider marking this as the answer.

Comment: depending on the data you might need to do `...h.CheckIssue IN (select CONVERT(char(10), max(paydate)) AS CheckIssue...`

Comment: @TDPotts that subquery is getting MAX so it will only ever be a single row. :D

Comment: @ SeanLange apologies

Comment: No need to apologize at all. It is well worth pointing out that if the max was removed from that subquery this will fail if there are more than 1 row with a status like 'PAID%'.